# Disable wpautop, keep line breaks

Tags: wp-autop

How can I disable automatic paragraph tags, but retain line breaks?

I have used this to remove wpautop:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

But there are no more line breaks in the text.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you mean? You want `<br />` tags, I assume? ([EOLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) should be there)

Comment: Yes, I want br tags. Do you mean a simple nl2br function should do it?

Comment: Yes, a simple nl2br function did it!

Comment: @Pier Add a real answer with your working code please. Accept that answer and get some rep. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the full solution.

First disable wpautop in your functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Then parse your content/excerpt with nl2br (a standard PHP function).

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'nl2br' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'nl2br' );
```

Comment: That will work, but it's very rudimentary, so you'll need to be look out for unintended side effects. For example, shortcodes will probably no longer work.

Comment: I wouldn't make this a filter, for that reason, but I would put it in single-post.php as echo nl2br(do_shortcode($post->post_content), true);  Otherwise, allowing wpautop creates a whole host of other problems with your html in posts.